# Automate 7-Zip extraction Windows8 - Tree Structure Folders

Tags: command-line, automation, 7-zip

I'm using 7-zip from command line to automate extraction of some files .dat from archives .gz

Here is the point:

Mother_folder contains several Daughter_subfolders. 
Each of the Daughters contain *.gz files.

I want 7-zip to search through ALL THE SUBFOLDERS AVAILABLE during extraction,
is there any sytax suitable for this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to wrote a script that works for me:

```
cd C:\\...\\Mother_folder

FOR /D /r %%g IN ("*") DO (  

     pushd %%g
     FOR /R %%f IN (*.gz) DO (
            "C:\...\7-Zip\7z.exe" e -o%%g %%f
                              )
     popd
)
```

It loops through all the subfolders of Mother_folder and uses them as current directory each time: pushd %%g.

In each of the subfolders every *.gz archive is extracted in %%g current directory and than the loop moves to the following subfolder to search for other *.gz archives to extract.

If you want to modify the location of the extracted files you can change the -o%%g to -o%%C:..\directory_you_want